# Changing frames of multiple UIView dependent on each other doesn't work efficiently in dispatch main queue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview

I have to change multiple UI's as `imageView` (Background for Label) is dependent on `label` (as text changes dynamically it increases dynamically). And avatar is always below label_bg_img.

So I have realised that frames of label change and hence  I assign the same `frame of label` to `imageView` taking into account the padding required too.

Also, I have a complicated layout with many element in it. And there are lot of UI component updated simultaneously.

And here is the code. Which cause a lot of randomness:

```
func changeFrame(){
  DispatchQueue.main.async{

    self.label_bg_img.frame = CGRect(x: self.label_bg_img.frame.minX, y: 100, width: self.label_txt.frame.width + 15, height: self.label_txt.frame.height + self.label_txt.frame.height/3)

    self.label_txt.center = self.label_bg_img.center

    self.label_txt.center.y = self.label_bg_img.center.y - 5

    self.avatar.frame = CGRect(x: self.label_bg_img.frame.maxX - self.avatar.frame.width, y: self.label_bg_img.frame.maxY, width: self.avatar.frame.width, height: self.avatar.frame.height)

  }
}
```

So frames do change sometimes but sometimes they don't. I have also created a button which calls the function changeFrame. So If I click on this button in some 4 - 5 times the frames are into correct form as I want them to be.

I have realized that I am missing something with frame update. or the synchronization in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use Autolayout to do this instead of changing directly the frame size

Comment: Hey @TomCobo AutoLayout in my understanding is used for frames to change on changing layout by rotating devices. But I want to do it explicitly on a button call.

Comment: Autolayout is an iOS engine that simplify the way you can interact with the Views. Modifying constraints you can change sizes and positions. Which makes easier to manage changes in the layout with rotations. Believe me, it'd do thounsand times easier for you this change. Have a look at this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started if you want to add them in the storyboard

Comment: Oh Thanks man. I read the whole tutorial. But then realized. I have already used all the things as explained in the tutorial. But my problem here is that once my view is set. Post that on pressing next I want to move the view to a new location and also update the label and its background simultaneously.  which is creating issue.